# mysql select COUNT join is failing to return records that don't match

Tags: mysql

I'm using the current sql:

```
SELECT 
    applications.*, 
    COUNT(pricingplans.PricingPlanID) AS PricingPlanCount

FROM 
    applications

LEFT OUTER JOIN pricingplans ON
    pricingplans.ApplicationID = applications.ApplicationID
```

The problem is that one application has 1 pricing plan to link to... The other does not, so I only get results back for the one that could satisfy the join.. whereas I really want it to say 0 if an application could not satisfy the join...

What am I doing wrong... I thought LEFT OUTER JOIN was for that specific reason?

**applications table:**
contains 2 applications.

**pricingplans table:**
contains 1 pricing plan that links to 1 of the above applications

**my query:**
returns only 1 result because only 1 of the JOINS could be satisfied... I want to actually have both applications come back but the count would say 0 coz it couldn't do a join.

Comment: So what is the exact result you're getting back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything like..

```
SELECT 
    applications.*, 
    COUNT(pricingplans.PricingPlanID) AS PricingPlanCount

FROM 
    applications

LEFT JOIN pricingplans ON
    pricingplans.ApplicationID = applications.ApplicationID

GROUP BY
    applications.ApplicationID
```

Comment: When you use Aggregate functions like COUNT/SUM and have multiple ids, GROUP BY is required. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html